# Mongodb cursor.hasNext() hangs?

Tags: java, mongodb

Using mongodb 2.6.  From Java, I'm going through a list of keys and generating a bunch of statistics for each key, involving some queries to Mongo (on a remote server).  As I generate each key's statistics, I write it to a file, so I'm not running out of memory locally.  At some point in the run (it changes each time), the code hangs on what appears to be something entirely innocuous - the check for curs.hasNext() in the following code. The query is a little slow, but it seems to run fine up until some variable point, when it no longer does.

```
BasicDBObject idMatch = new BasicDBObject(Constants.USER_ID_STR, userid);
// get the earliest  tweet
DBCursor curs = this.tweetsCollection.find(idMatch).sort(new BasicDBObject(Constants.TWEETED_AT_STR, Constants.ASCENDING_SORT_FLAG)).limit(1);
Date theDate = null;
if (curs.hasNext()){
    DBObject obj = curs.next();
    theDate = (Date) obj.get(Constants.TWEETED_AT_STR);
}
return theDate;
```

Comment: Can you quantify? Hangs for how long? Have you tried correlating mongostat output to the time in question? Do you have an index on the userid and tweetedAt?

Comment: Hangs indefinitely, until I kill it.  Up to two days (happened over the weekend).  I do have indexes on both user_id and tweeted_at.  As I mentioned in another question, I am considering adding a compound index to speed up the query, but right now, I'm far more concerned about the apparent hanging problem.  I ran the identical query in the shell and it returned fine.

Comment: I would suggest that you go back and look at your mongod logs at the time of the hang. If you can reproduce, try running db.currentOp() at the time that it hangs.

Comment: Do you have an idea how many times this code is called prior to it hanging? I know it varies a bit but can you give us a rough idea? 10 times, 100 times, 1000 times?

Comment: It varies a lot.  Once it hung after maybe 30 times, a couple of times around 250, a couple over 400.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this problem? I suspect the issue here could be related to server/network connectivity (i.e. the server stops responding to the open cursor, or there is a periodic delay when the server fetches the next [batch of results](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/cursors/#cursor-batches)(. Have you checked for any correlation with entries in your MongoDB log or server metrics/resources? I would suggest using a service like [MMS Monitoring](https://mms.mongodb.com) if you don't have a monitoring solution in place yet.

Comment: I wasn't able to resolve it directly, but it 'just worked', so it may have been network glitches.